# Why is there is no specifications for file format (e.g. HLS or DASH) in Media Source Extension?

Tags: http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, media-source

I'm trying to understand what does impose support of certain media file formats by different browsers.

Why there is no specifications for file format (e.g. HLS or DASH) in [Media Source Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Source_Extensions)? And if file format is not specified by MSE, then which standart specifies it? Is it up just to browser implementation?

Comment: I second @aergistal but this link might also be helpful. https://bitmovin.com/browser-capabilities/

Answer (score 2):

`HLS` and `DASH` are not file formats, they are adaptive streaming standards. They can use various containers and codecs.

For MSE there's a registry of byte stream formats here: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/mse-byte-stream-format-registry/

At the time of writing they are `WebM`, `MP4`, `MPEG-2 TS` and `MPEG`/`AAC` audio-only.

Comment: If MSE specifies only byte stream formats, then which standard specifies support of `DASH` and `HLS` in browsers?

Comment: @Jofsey The purpose of MSE is to allow you to offload decoding via JavaScript so you can just write a JavaScript player for a specific standard like `DASH` or `HLS` or whatever. What varies is browser support for various containers/codecs because of patents and competition. There's no standard for the latter.